# Can I use an external 3G SAS device with a 12G card?

Tags: raid, hardware, sas

I want to connect an old 3G SAS DAS (Dell MD1000) to a new 12G RAID controller (PERC H830 or something LSI 3108-based).  I assumed it would be backwards-compatible like SATA1/2/3 is, but after closer examination I'm having doubts.

Dell's [PERC site](http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/04/campaigns/dell-raid-controllers) (click the "External Storage" tab) says many devices are supported with adapters, but the MD1000 on anything 6G or 12G instead says "no support".

When I checked my supplier for a 12G-to-3G cable (SFF-8644 to SFF-8470), they had nothing.  When I google for one, I get a small amount of results from brands I'm familiar with.  Whereas a 12G-to-6G cable (SFF-8644 to SFF-8088) is available from Lenovo, HP, ATTO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you use the right cable. Speeds will obviously downshift to the lowest common speed (3G).

Is there a chance you can use a period-correct card or server instead?